# Swift modify Int array for InsertionSort algorithm

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm very new to Swift and I wanted to know how I'm supposed to modify an `Int` contained in my `Int[]`? I made it like I'd do it in Java but it, obviously, doesn't work: I get a `Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'Int'` compilation error.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

func createRandomArray(length: Int) -> [Int]{
     var random = [Int]()
     for index in 0...length{
         random.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
     }
     return random
}

func insertionSort(toSort: [Int]) -> [Int]{
    var length = toSort.count
    for index in 1...length-1{
        var key = toSort[index]
        var previous = index-1
        while(previous>0 && toSort[previous]>key){
            // ERROR IS THERE
            toSort[previous+1] = toSort[previous]
            previous--
        }
    }
    return toSort
}

var array = createRandomArray(10)

print(array)

print(insertionSort(array))
```

I thought that using a `var` instead of `let` will give a mutable object so that's why I'm a bit lost.

Thanks for help

**EDIT:**

I got this working answer yet, thanks to @vacawama:

```
import Foundation

func createRandomArray(length: Int) -> [Int]{
     var random = [Int]()
     for index in 0...length{
         random.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
     }
     return random
}

func insertionSort(var toSort: [Int]) -> [Int]{
    for firstIterator in 1...toSort.count-1{
        var currentValue = toSort[firstIterator]
        var previousPosition = firstIterator-1
        while(previousPosition>=0 && toSort[previousPosition]>currentValue){
            swap(&toSort[previousPosition+1], &toSort[previousPosition])
            previousPosition--
        }
    }
    return toSort
}


var array = createRandomArray(10)

print(array)

print(insertionSort(array))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updated Answer for Swift 5.x and Beyond

Swift has had many changes in the 7 years since I answered this question.  It is no longer valid to insert `var` into the function header to make an array modifiable.  The modern way to do that is to make `var toSort = toSort` the first line of the function body.

Here is a modification of the OP's code with modern Swift updates:

```
func createRandomArray(_ length: Int) -> [Int] {
    var random = [Int]()
    for _ in 0..<length {
        random.append(Int.random(in: 0..<100))
    }
    return random
}

func insertionSort(_ toSort: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var toSort = toSort
    for firstIterator in 1..<toSort.count {
        let currentValue = toSort[firstIterator]
        var previousPosition = firstIterator - 1
        while (previousPosition >= 0 && toSort[previousPosition] > currentValue) {
            toSort.swapAt(previousPosition + 1, previousPosition)
            previousPosition -= 1
        }
    }
    return toSort
}
    
var array = createRandomArray(10)

print(array)

print(insertionSort(array))
```

---

A shorter version of `createRandomArray`:

```
func createRandomArray(_ length: Int) -> [Int] {
    (0..<length).map { _ in .random(in: 0..<100) }
}
```

---

Note:  Your `insertionSort()` will crash if it is passed an empty array.  Add this `guard` statement to the start of the function body to prevent that:

```
guard !toSort.isEmpty else { return toSort }
```

---

#### Original Answer (now obsolete) for Swift 1.0

By default, array parameters are immutable within the called function. If you want to modify the copy of the array that is passed to `insertionSort`, add `var` before `toSort` in the function header.

```
func insertionSort(var toSort: [Int]) -> [Int]{
```

Answer (score 0):

I played with the following using swift 3. Hope it'll help some people who come here.

```
import Cocoa

func ints(cnt: Int, ceiling: Int) -> [Int] {
    var arr = [Int]()
    for _ in 0 ..< cnt {
        arr.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ceiling))))
    }
    return arr
}

func insertion(arr: inout [Int]) {
    for i in 1..<arr.count {
        var j = i
        let x = arr[i]
        while j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > x {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1]
            j -= 1
        }
        arr[j] = x
    }
}

let a = ints(cnt: 10, ceiling: 100)
print(a)

var b = a
insertion(arr: &b)
print(b)
```

output:

```
[13, 30, 68, 19, 1, 4, 28, 65, 96, 13]
[1, 4, 13, 13, 19, 28, 30, 65, 68, 96]
```

For comparison, here is an implementaion in java:

```
void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int x = arr[i];
        int j = i;
        while(j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > x) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j] = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct InsertionSort {
    
    static func sort(data: Array<Int> = [5,9,1,8,2,4,3,1]) {
        var data = data
        for (i, e) in data.enumerated() where i > 0 && e < data[i - 1]  {
            traverseBackwardAndSwap(i, &data)
        }
        
        printData(data)
    }
    
    private static func traverseBackwardAndSwap(_ i: Int, _ data: inout [Int]) {
        for i in (0...i).reversed() where i > 0 && data[i] < data[i-1] {
            let temp = data[i]
            data[i] = data[i-1]
            data[i-1] = temp
        }
    }
    
    private static func printData(_ data: [Int]) {
        for e in data {
            print("\(e)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5**: **Generic Insertion sort**

```
func insertionSort<U: Comparable>(with array: inout [U]) -> [U] {
    for i in 1..<array.count {
        let temp = array[i]
        var insertionIndex = i
        for j in (0...i).reversed() where j>0 && temp < array[j-1] {
            array[j] = array[j-1]
            insertionIndex = j-1
        }
        array[insertionIndex] = temp
    }
    return array
}
```

**Input:-**

```
var intArray = [8, 3, 5, 10, 4, -1, 17, 3, 18, 10]
var floatArray = [12.231, 12.23, 14.5, 3.4, 67.899, 0.0, -1.234]
var doubleArray = [123.43555, 123.1223332, -121.2212, 23.343434, 1.232434]
var stringArray = ["Ratheesh", "Srini", "Thangu", "Muthu", "Gopi"]

print(insertionSort(with: &intArray))
print(insertionSort(with: &floatArray))
print(insertionSort(with: &doubleArray))
print(insertionSort(with: &stringArray))
```

**Output:-**

```
[-1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 10, 17, 18]
[-1.234, 0.0, 3.4, 12.23, 12.231, 14.5, 67.899]
[-121.2212, 1.232434, 23.343434, 123.1223332, 123.43555]
["Gopi", "Muthu", "Ratheesh", "Srini", "Thangu"]
```